# 2004 Nissan sentra 1.8L

Tags: nissan, oil-leak, sentra

I was driving the car and I was suspecting low oil but the oil light never came on. I just got off the highway and made my way through town when the car made a knocking /ticking sound almost sounded like the exhaust came off and was being dragged.. Then smoke came from under the hood where the oil hit the hot engine parts. Little to no oil dripped from under the car as most of it was as sprayed from the back of the engine.

I filled new motor oil and oil filter as the filter was extremely loose. Initially I thought the leak was coming from the filter, however after replacing the leak is still continuing from somewhere on the back of the engine. Not sure if hose, oil temp senor, crack or something else? The car starts but has almost no power. Very rough idle and spits out oil everywhere.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I think you'll need to figure out where the oil is coming from ... it could be any of those things you're suggesting. Something to remember about oil is, like most liquids, it won't flow uphill. As long as it isn't spraying out, you'll not find oil above where the leak is occurring. Track the oil back up the block until you can figure out where it's coming from ... I don't know if your Sentra has an oil cooler, but it probably doesn't. I would suggestion you run it only what you need to and not any more. You're probably doing more damage than good

Comment: More than likely the oil pressure sensor is leaking and would also explain why the oil light never came on, replace the oil pressure sensor.

Comment: There is a massive hole that I found in the block right under the oil filter. Needs new motor. I suspect connecting rod made the hole